# Як влучніше перекласти "trailer", коли йдеться про фільм чи гру?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Відповідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84)):

> **Тре́йлер** — відеоролик, який складається з коротких і зазвичай найбільш видовищних уривків фільму для його анонсування або реклами. Відеоряд з незв'язаних уривків і сцен за принципом калейдоскопа іноді змінюються дуже швидко: більше справляють враження на глядача, ніж залишають осмислене уявлення про фільм.
> Термін застосовується і до комп'ютерних ігор.

Також Вікіпедія згадує про: анонс, рекламу, дражнилку, демоверсію.

На Словотворі [пропонують](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/treiler) наступні варіанти:

> вістовик, передвíсник, кіноанонс, завáбка, передуйко, провісник, передпоказ та інші

СУМ-11, зазначає:

щодо [*вістовика*](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD):

> ВІСТОВИ́К, а́, ч.,рідко. Те саме, що вісту́н
>
> ВІСТУ́Н, а́, ч. 1. Той, хто приносить звістку.
> 2. перен. Те саме, що ві́сник

а щодо [*передвісника*](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA):

> 3. чого. Той (те), що своєю появою, поведінкою і т. ін. віщує які-небудь зміни в природі (про рослини, тварин, явища природи тощо).

То який український відповідник був би більш влучніший до терміну "trailer", як Ви гадаєте? Чи може він вже існує?

Comment: **Передпоказ** - це демонстрація цілого фільму до офіційної прем'єри [У Києві відбувся передпоказ фільму "Кіборги"](http://asn.in.ua/ua/news/publishing/138419-film-ne-o-vojjne-a-o-mire-v-kieve-sostojalsja-pred.html).

Answer (score 2):

На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/tyzer) є також таке іншомовне слово як "тизер" і хоч є деяка різниця між "тизер-трейлером" і "трейлером" (а саме те, що "тизер" зазвичай коротший і триває до однієї хвилини), однак завдання у них одне і те саме - викликати зацікавлення у аудиторії, а також реклама фільму, товару чи комп'ютерної гри. Тому, як на мене, варіант "завабка" (від слова "заваблювати") може підійти як відповідник до слова "трейлер".

Також, можу запропонувати варіант "відео-приманка" або "відео-оголошення".

Comment: Слово _забавка_ — це річ дльа _забави_. Мајете проблеми з коріньами, хоча хід думки мені подобаје сьа. А так, то дльа мене це је _рекламоју_, тобто _оголошенньа_ та _приманка_ тут непогано заходить. Ја б шче додав _заманувка_, бо _приманка_ зазвичај працьује до кінцевого результату, тобто походить від доконаного дьіјеслова _приманити_.

Comment: @follower, вибачте, але офіційні мови спілкування на даному сайті - лише украjінська та англійська.

Answer (score 0):

Є українське слово *звістка*, то чому не можна перекласти слово *трейлер* як ***звістун***?

Такий переклад послідовно вживають деякі YouTube-канали:

- [Українець Ukrajinets Русин Rusyn](//www.youtube.com/@ukrajinetsrusyn7263/search?query=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD);
- [Фолькльорія / Folklorija Etnospivanka Etnomuzyka](//www.youtube.com/@folklorijaetnospivankaetno4117/search?query=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD).

Comment: Якщо Ви не заперечите, я доповнив Вашу відповідь прикладами вживання цього слова (у цьому значенні) в мережі. Загалом на цьому сайті більш полюбляють розлогі відповіді, з аргументацією і посиланнями — хоча іноді, на мій погляд, це прагнення надто сильне — на жаль, робить наш сайт непривітним до новачків. Вибачте за це.